If $x^5+x^6 = 1$, then $x^{14}+4x^{13}+5x^{12}+2x^{11}+x^{5}+x^{6}$ is equivalent to ...

If $x^5+x^6 = 1$, then the value of the expression $x^{14}+4x^{13}+5x^{12}+2x^{11}+x^{5}+x^{6}$ is equivalent to
A) $\;(x+1)^2 \quad$ B) $\;(x+2)^2 \quad$
C) $\;(x+13)^2 \quad$
D) $\;(x+11)^2$

My Attempt
Given the equation $x^5 + x^6 = 1$ , we want to evaluate:
$x^{14} + 4x^{13} + 5x^{12} + 2x^{11} + x^5 + x^6$
First, I isolated $x^6$  from the given equation:
$x^6 = 1 - x^5$
Substituting $x^6$  back into the expression, I got:
$x^{14} + 4x^{13} + 5x^{12} + 2x^{11} + x^5 + (1 - x^5)$
= $x^{14} + 4x^{13} + 5x^{12} + 2x^{11} + 1$
Now, I  expressed everything in terms of lower powers of $x$. Notice that $x^5$  and $x^6$  form a cyclic relationship due to the original equation. My first thought was that there might be a factorization involving a common term, but I couldn't find a direct simplification.
Then I tried using polynomial identities, specifically considering the possibility that $x^{14} + 4x^{13} + 5x^{12} + 2x^{11}$  might factor as $(x^7 + ax^6 + bx^5)^2$, but the coefficients didn't match up correctly when I expanded.
At this point, I started testing values numerically and realized that when  $x \approx 1$ , the expression seems to roughly approach 9, which is $(x+2)^2$. But the correct answer given in the answer key was option(A).
Can anyone please help me in arriving at the answer in a systematic way

Whenever we see two terms of the form $x^{n+6}+x^{n+5}$, we can replace them with $x^n$. So...
$$\begin{align}x^{14}+4x^{13}+5x^{12}+2x^{11}+x^6+x^5 &=(x^{14}+x^{13})+3(x^{13}+x^{12})+2(x^{12}+x^{11})+(x^6+x^5)\\
&=x^8+3x^7+2x^6+1\\
&=(x^8+x^7)+2(x^7+x^6)+1\\
&=x^2+2x+1
\end{align}$$

Same as computing its remainder $!\bmod x^6+x^5-1.\ $ Same as David's prior answer. $\ \ $

@BillDubuque: In essence, yes. But mine is intelligible.

Rewrite:
$$x^{14} + 4x^{13} + 5x^{12} + 2x^{11} + x^5 + x^6$$
$$ = x^{14}+x^{13}+3x^{13}+3x^{12}+2x^{12}+2x^{11}+x^5+x^6$$
Factor something out of each pair now giving something you already know the value of along with the common coefficient.
$$x^8+3x^7+2x^6+1$$
Doing this again,
$$ = x^8+x^7+2x^7+2x^6+1 = x^2(x^6+x^5)+2x(x^6+x^5)+1  = x^2+2x+1$$

Same as computing its remainder $!\bmod x^6+x^5-1.\ \ $

Start with $x^6=1-x^5$ and systematically iterate. So $x^7=x-x^6=x^5+x-1$ until $x^{14}=- 5x^5 + x^4 - x^3 + 2x^2 - 3x + 4$. Then
$$
x^{14}+4x^{13}+5x^{12}+2x^{11}+x^{5}+x^{6}=x^2+2x+1.
$$

i.e. compute its remainder $!\bmod x^6+x^5-1\ \ $

We can solve this systematically using polynomial long division, dividing $x^{14}+4x^{13}+5x^{12}+2x^{11}+x^6+x^5\;\;$ by $\;\;x^6+x^5-1$, which results in
$$
x^{14}+4x^{13}+5x^{12}+2x^{11}+x^6+x^5 \\
=(x^8+3x^7+2x^6+x^2+2x+1)(x^6+x^5-1)\;+\;(x^2+2x+1)
$$
When we now use that $x^6+x^5-1=0$, we directly get
$$
x^{14}+4x^{13}+5x^{12}+2x^{11}+x^6+x^5 = (x+1)^2
$$

We only need the remainder (not the quotient) so we can use easier modular arithmetic (e.g. as done by rewrite rules in other answers).

@BillDubuque I wanted to show an approach that does not depend on the special structure of the given polynomial and does not depend on the fact that the answer must be one of a certain set of given choices. The method with the polynomial long division works for general input, and you do not have to be lucky and spot certain properties of a particular polynomial. You do not have to be lucky to spot (or guess) a suitable modulus, like $31$, either. I am convinced that there is much more to learn from a general approach than from a solution that only works for a particular set of input data.

@BillDubuque Regarding the quotient: I agree, it is not required. It is not necessary to write it down while you are doing the calculations. However, I think the solution is more comprehensible if it contains the quotient. And it is a by-product of the systematic calculation of the remainder during the polynomial long division, anyway, it does not increase the effort.

One way I thought - which is opportunist rather than systematic is that $$1=\left(x^6+x^5\right)^2=x^{12}+2x^{11}+x^{10}$$ so that $$x^2=x^{14}+2x^{13}+x^{12}$$
That gives us $$x^{14}+4x^{13}+5x^{12}+2x^{11}+x^6+x^5=x^2+2x^{13}+4x^{12}+2x^{11}+1$$
And then (back to that squared expression at the beginning) $2x^{13}+4x^{12}+2x^{11}=2x$
It won't always work but it is a way of doing polynomial division to reduce the high exponents more quickly.

First of all we will factorise the expression
$x^{14}+4x^{13}+5x^{12}+2x^{11}+x^{6}+x^{5}$
Split the terms $4x^{13}$ and $5x^{12}$
$x^{14}+(x^{13}+3x^{13})+(3x^{12}+2x^{12})+2x^{11}+x^{6}+x^5$
Now rearrange the expression
$3x^{12}+x^{13}+2x^{11}+x^{5}+3x^{13}+x^{14}+2x^{12}+x^{6}$
$x^5(3x^7+x^8+2x^6+1)+x^6(3x^7+x^8+2x^6+1)$
$(3x^7+x^8+2x^6+1)(x^5+x^6)$
Now split the term $3x^7$ inside the bracket
$(x^7+2x^7+x^8+2x^6+1)(x^5+x^6)$
Now rearrange the terms in the first bracket
$(x^7+x^8+2x^6+2x^7+1)(x^5+x^6)$
$[x^2(x^5+x^6)+2x(x^5+x^6)+1](x^5+x^6)$
Since $x^5+x^6 = 1$
The Expression boils down to
$x^2+2x+1$
$(x+1)²$
Therefore option (A) is correct

Great Approach  liked it

You can write a higher exponent as x^{14}, resulting in $x^{14}$.

@CircuitSage Have you seen Tony's answer? It is much shorter and easier.

$f(x)=q(x)(\color{#c00}{x^6\!+\!x^5\!-\!1})+r(x)\overset{\color{#c00}{x\,=\,-2}}\Longrightarrow$ $\, r(-2)\equiv f(-2)\equiv \color{#0af}1\pmod{\!\color{#c00}{\!31}}.\,$
For $\,{\rm (A)}\!:\ r(x)=(x\!+\!1)^2\,$ we have  $\,r(-2)\equiv \color{#0af}1\,$ as sought, but others are $\equiv 0^2,11^2,9^2\not\equiv 1$.

Generally, this modular-check method may be easier than some of the other methods, so I thought it worth mention.

I think that $31$ is a big number for modular arithmetic in a test. And lots of evaluations at $-2$. Good luck in a test.

@Bob it's trivial: $,< 20$ secs of mental arithmetic: clearly $ 0^2,11^2,9^2!\not\equiv 1\pmod{!31},,$ and
$$\begin{align}f(x)&=\ \ \ \ \  x^{11},{(x^3!+!4x^2!+!5x!+!2)}+\color{#0af}1\
\Rightarrow\ \ f(-2)&=(-2)^{11}(\color{darkorange}{-8!+!16-10!+!2})+\color{#0af}1 = \color{darkorange}0!+!\color{#0af}1\end{align}\qquad$$
I chose $,\color{#c00}{x = -2},$ so to minimize the value of our modulus $,\color{#c00}{x^6!+!x^5!−!\color{#0af}1}\ \ $

Well. $x=1$ is better to minimize! @Bill Dubuque

@Bob No, because it yields $1$ which is not a (useful) modulus. $\ \ $

We have that
$$x^{6}+x^{5}=(x^{6}+x^{5})^2=x^{12}+2x^{11}+x^{10}=x^{10}(x+1)^2=1$$
then
$$x^{14}+4x^{13}+5x^{12}+2x^{11}+\overbrace{x^{5}+x^{6}}^{x^{12}+2x^{11}+x^{10}}=x^{14}+4x^{13}+6x^{12}+4x^{11}+x^{10}=$$
$$=x^{10}(x+1)^4=\overbrace{x^{10}(x+1)^2}^{1}(x+1)^2=(x+1)^2$$

The given high-powered polynomial can be written as
$$x^{11}(x+1)^2(x+2)+1$$
Hence, it reduces to
$$\stackrel{x+1=\tfrac1{x^5}}=x^{11}\left(\frac1{x^5}\right)^2(x+2)+1$$
$$=(x+1)^2$$
I am sorry if it is dupe answer.

It's a bit ad-hoc w/o saying how to discover  the factorization $,f(x) = x^3!+!4x^2!+!5x!+!2 = (x!+!1)^2(x!+!2)$. One way: alternating coef sum of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ are both zero, so $-1$ is a double root. $\ \ $

I did polynomial division $p(x)÷:x+1$ by hand. Then, $x^2+3x+2$ is easy. @BillDubuque

That's a verification,  not a motivated discovery. Why would a student look for such a factorization in the first place? The problem with ad hoc methods like this is that they will rarely work generally. But computing its remainder $!\bmod x^6 + x^5-1,$ always works, requires no ingenuity, and it is very efficient (does not require any factorization). That's essentially what most all other answers do (w/o explicitly saying so).

I did that way too, grouping the terms... It was a long way. I shortened. @BillDubuque

Since $x=-1$ is a root by Ruffini or long division we obtain
$$x^{14}+4x^{13}+5x^{12}+2x^{11}+x^{5}+x^{6}=(x+1)(x^{13} + 3 x^{12} + 2 x^{11} + x^{5})=x^{10}(x+1)^4=(x+1)^2$$
indeed
$$\require{cancel}x^{13} + 3 x^{12} + 2 x^{11} + x^{5}=x^{13} + 3 x^{12} + 3 x^{11}+x^{10} -x^{11}-x^{10}+ x^{5}=x^{10}(x+1)^3\cancel{-x^5(x^6+x^5)}+\cancel{x^5}$$
and
$$x^5(x+1)=1 \implies x^{10}(x+1)^2=1$$
